# Can't scroll to the bottom if content too long Sencha Touch 2

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch-2

Can't scroll to the bottom if content too long

Why it can't scroll to the bottom if the content too long?

```js
this._panel = {            
     xtype: 'panel',
     height: '100%',
     scrollable: true,
     items: [{
          html: '<img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29400000/Iron-Man-Tony-Stark-the-avengers-29489238-2124-2560.jpg" />'
          }, {
          html: '<img src="http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29400000/Iron-Man-Tony-Stark-the-avengers-29489238-2124-2560.jpg" />'
     }]
};

this.add(this._panel);
```

Comment: Maybe try giving your panel `layout:'vbox'`.

Comment: Also get in trouble with the scrolling all the time. Whatever settings I choose Sencha always finds a few ui elements that can be reached with scrolling, but then they shoot back down :(

Answer (score 0):

Im adding your code as an item of Ext.Container, Ext.Panel, or Ext.navigation.View and in all cases I can scroll to the bottom. I think is due to some config you have set in 'this'.
What component (xtype) is it?